# Automatically forward bitcoins from address A to Address C At 0 confirmations?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, raw-transaction

I run a bitcoin full node,at that node i have an Address A.

Assuming that Address A receive an Amount from Address B.(i can get UTXO information from blockchain.info API)
How can I automaticlly resend the received amount To an Address C (on 0 confirmations) before its display in my wallet.

In fact i want to create a raw transaction with that UTXO information (txid,vout and amount) and send it to Address C.

That UTXO belong to my private key so i can sign it and send it to the network.

Transaction must be created and send to the network before block is confirmed, so that in most cases the receiving transaction and sending transaction are confirmed in the same block that is mined.

This is technically possible, because I have seen this many times (https://explorer.bitcoin.com/btc/address/1Nc4oHe7TeDNjnvGfm7ZB6Pi2YtkST9znn).

But the question is how ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: "Transaction must be created and send to the network before block is confirmed" Why do you need this? What is your motive?

Comment: I work for some kind of bitcoin development tests.
I just want to (receive and send) the same amount of BTC in the same block.
Address A-> Address B -> address C (in the same block).
In fact i want to create a raw transaction with the UTXO (that is not confirmed yet) sign it with my private key and send it to the network (that UTXO belong to me).
I was wondering if that possible or no.